# Drawing large amount lines .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, charts, gdi, direct2d

I have been looking for a while as to how i can improve the rendering performance of my waveform chart.
Currently i am using a (as much as i think possible) optimized GDI based rendering routine:

```
Private Sub Calculate2(ByVal aData()() As Double)
    'aData size: 1000 traces with 200k points each -> Dim aData(1000, 200000)

    'Some data preparations doing roughly the same as they would in the real app
    Dim PS_Y As Double = 1
    Dim Origin As PointF = New PointF(Rnd() * 100, Rnd() * 100)
    PS_Y = Rnd() + 0.1
    Dim Data(), ST As Double
    Dim lPoints As New List(Of PointF)
    Dim PS_X As Double = Rnd() + 0.1

    'Graphics initialisation
    Dim Img As New Bitmap(900, 600)
    Dim ImgGR As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Img)
    ImgGR.Clear(Color.White)
    Dim WFPen As New Pen(Brushes.Black, 1)

    'Cache property values for faster access:
    Dim l As Integer = 100 'ChartRect.Left
    Dim r As Integer = 1000 'ChartRect.Right

    'Process trace by trace:
    For i = 0 To aData.Length - 1
        ST = Rnd() 'x distance of the points
        Data = aData(i) 'y values, 1 per x value

        If Data.Length = 0 Then Continue For

        'scale precalculations, first & last displayed points:
        Dim ScaleX As Double = ST * PS_X
        Dim OrigX As Single = Origin.X

        Dim iStart As Integer = (l - OrigX) / ScaleX
        Dim iEnd As Integer = (r - OrigX) / ScaleX
        If iStart < 0 Then iStart = 0
        If iEnd < 0 Then iEnd = 0
        If iEnd > Data.Length - 1 Then iEnd = Data.Length - 1
        If iStart > Data.Length - 1 Then iStart = Data.Length - 1

        'Make sure that for benchmarking purposes all points are displayed, next 2 lines do not exist in real code:
        iStart = 0
        iEnd = Data.Length - 1

        If iEnd < iStart Then Continue For

        'point calculations using the pecalculated values:
        Dim APT(iEnd - iStart) As PointF
        For j = iStart To iEnd
            APT(j - iStart) = Origin + New SizeF(j * ScaleX, -(Data(j) * PS_Y))
        Next



        ImgGR.DrawLines(WFPen, APT)
        'Commenting out this line reduces the time needed for executing this whole routine from 42.4s to 4.76s
        'Hence most of the time spent even with all the scaling is still in rendering the spline.
    Next
```

I have tried an approach with Direct2D but that was even much slower than the "DrawLines" method in GDI:

```
 'Imports D2D = Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.DirectX.Direct2D1
'Imports DX = Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.DirectX
Dim TGT As D2D.RenderTarget
Private Sub initd2d()
    Dim fac As D2D.D2DFactory = D2D.D2DFactory.CreateFactory(Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.DirectX.Direct2D1.D2DFactoryType.SingleThreaded)

    Dim imgf As DX.WindowsImagingComponent.ImagingFactory
    imgf = DX.WindowsImagingComponent.ImagingFactory.Create

    'Dim pf As New D2D.PixelFormat(DX.Graphics.Format.B8G8R8A8UNorm, D2D.AlphaMode.Ignore)
    Dim pf As New D2D.PixelFormat(DX.Graphics.Format.Unknown, D2D.AlphaMode.Unknown)

    Dim bmp As DX.WindowsImagingComponent.ImagingBitmap
    bmp = imgf.CreateImagingBitmap(CUInt(900), CUInt(600), DX.WindowsImagingComponent.PixelFormats.Pbgra32Bpp, DX.WindowsImagingComponent.BitmapCreateCacheOption.CacheOnLoad)

    Dim rtp As New D2D.RenderTargetProperties(D2D.RenderTargetType.Default, pf, 0, 0, D2D.RenderTargetUsages.None, Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.DirectX.Direct3D.FeatureLevel.Default)
    TGT = fac.CreateWicBitmapRenderTarget(bmp, rtp)


    TGT.Clear(New D2D.ColorF(Color.White.ToArgb))
End Sub

'104,7s execution time:
Private Sub drawd2d()
    Dim p1 As New D2D.Point2F(1, 10.5)
    Dim p2 As New D2D.Point2F(1.01, 10)
    Dim b As D2D.Brush = TGT.CreateSolidColorBrush(New D2D.ColorF(0, 0, 255))
    TGT.BeginDraw()

    For i = 0 To 200000 * 1000
        TGT.DrawLine(p1, p2, b, 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

The data dimensions are commonly used in this application so please do not ask why i need it.

I also know it must be somehow possible to display it much faster as the application generating the data in the first place manages to render 4 traces with 50M points in about 3 seconds, which is roughly the same data ammount.

If anyone has done something similar before, i'd very much appreciate it if you could point me towards the right direction, or if available give me an alternative how i can render the PointF-Array or a similar structure into a bitmap.

EDIT:
Please keep in mind that these are BENCHMARKING routines that are intended to do the same calculation as the original software without the need to load the rest of the program.
the Data()() array is dynamically generated by the software and thus the dimension have to be checked and acted upon.

The cleanup functions have been removed along with the data loading and picture displaying functions, grids and other code unrelated to the issue.

EDIT2:
code sample including data generation routine:

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim T As New HiResTimer
    Dim StartTime, StopTime As Long

    'initd2d()

    PrepareData(10, 200000)



    StartTime = T.Value
    For i = 1 To 1
        'drawd2d()
        Calculate2(100, 0, 200000)
    Next
    StopTime = T.Value

    Dim Elapsed As Double = (StopTime - StartTime) / T.Frequency
    Debug.Print("Time: " & Elapsed)

End Sub

Dim aData()() As Double
Private Sub PrepareData(ByVal WaveformCount As Integer, ByVal Length As Integer)
    Dim Offset As Double = 0
    Dim Amplitude As Double = 100

    Dim SineCount As Double = 4
    Dim SineBase As Double = 2 * Math.PI / Length * SineCount

    ReDim aData(WaveformCount - 1)
    For i = 0 To WaveformCount - 1
        ReDim aData(i)(Length - 1)

        For j = 0 To Length - 1
            aData(i)(j) = Amplitude * Math.Sin(SineBase * j) + Offset + Rnd() * Amplitude * 0.05
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Calculate2(ByVal AmplitudeUsed As Double, ByVal OffsetUsed As Double, ByVal LengthUsed As Integer)
    Dim PS_Y As Double

    'Instead of making this random, here a real calculation for the scale (chartheight / biggest waveform amplitude) :
    PS_Y = 600 / (AmplitudeUsed * 2 + AmplitudeUsed * 0.1)  ' Rnd() + 0.1

    'Since our calculation method oscillates around zero with the same amplitude we can predict that we need the following offset:
    Dim Origin As PointF = New PointF(0, 300)


    Dim Data(), ST As Double
    Dim lPoints As New List(Of PointF)

    'set the x axis scale to make our waveform fit exactly:
    Dim PS_X As Double = 900 / LengthUsed

    Dim Img As New Bitmap(900, 600)
    Dim ImgGR As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Img)
    ImgGR.Clear(Color.White)
    Dim WFPen As New Pen(Brushes.Black, 1)

    'theese 2 values simply define an area in the picture where the waveforms are actually visible to not overlap with the axis / legend, set it to something that makes sense
    Dim l As Integer = 20 'ChartRect.Left
    Dim r As Integer = 700 'ChartRect.Right

    For i = 0 To aData.Length - 1
        'Set sampletime to 1 second to keep the predefined scale from above, but still do the calculation as it would be needed with real data:
        ST = 1 ' Rnd()
        Data = aData(i)

        If Data.Length = 0 Then Continue For

        Dim ScaleX As Double = ST * PS_X
        Dim OrigX As Single = Origin.X

        Dim iStart As Integer = (l - OrigX) / ScaleX
        Dim iEnd As Integer = (r - OrigX) / ScaleX
        If iStart < 0 Then iStart = 0
        If iEnd < 0 Then iEnd = 0
        If iEnd > Data.Length - 1 Then iEnd = Data.Length - 1
        If iStart > Data.Length - 1 Then iStart = Data.Length - 1

        iStart = 0
        iEnd = Data.Length - 1

        If iEnd < iStart Then Continue For

        Dim APT(iEnd - iStart) As PointF
        For j = iStart To iEnd
            APT(j - iStart) = Origin + New SizeF(j * ScaleX, -(Data(j) * PS_Y))
        Next



        ImgGR.DrawLines(WFPen, APT)

    Next


    PictureBox1.Image = Img
End Sub
```

Comment: Much confusing code. I think you have much unnecessary code in there as well, you give `Data` a value then check it's `Length` - work on simplifying your code. Also you are not disposing you graphics objects - `Pens`, `Graphics`, etc...

Comment: @DonA the code is for benchmaring purposes only, please chech my edit for details

Comment: Is that 50M = 50,000,000 points?! How can one visualize that many lines?

Comment: @DonA they are oscilloscope waveforms, as to how they look i can not disclose but you can google for something like "oscilloscope waveform tektronix dpo" to see something similar

Comment: Do you have a dummy file I could test? I would like to get rid of the `Rnd()` part which may play a part in your problems.

Comment: @DonA just use constants or predefine the values before, as i said i cannot disclose any real data. the most realistic would be to generate a wave by having ScaleX = l/Data.length to fill the entire x axis, generate the yValues with a random algorithm that has a maximum change per point of about 5-10% of the total height. and choose ScaleY to also fill the bitmap.

Comment: @DonA added a sample including a realistic data generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the code block that optimizes the graph automatically, it does not help for many small waveforms, but it works wonders on the 10k and larger ones:

```
Private Function Calculate3(ByVal aData()() As Double, ByVal AmplitudeUsed As Double, ByVal OffsetUsed As Double, ByVal LengthUsed As Integer) As Bitmap
    Dim PS_Y As Double

    'Instead of making this random, here a real calculation for the scale (chartheight / biggest waveform amplitude) :
    PS_Y = 600 / (AmplitudeUsed * 2 + AmplitudeUsed * 0.1)  ' Rnd() + 0.1

    'Since our calculation method oscillates around zero with the same amplitude we can predict that we need the following offset:
    Dim Origin As PointF = New PointF(0, 300)


    Dim Data(), ST As Double
    Dim lPoints As New List(Of PointF)

    'set the x axis scale to make our waveform fit exactly:
    Dim PS_X As Double = 900 / LengthUsed

    Dim Img As New Bitmap(900, 600)
    Dim ImgGR As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Img)
    ImgGR.Clear(Color.White)
    Dim WFPen As New Pen(Brushes.Black, 1)

    'theese 2 values simply define an area in the picture where the waveforms are actually visible to not overlap with the axis / legend, set it to something that makes sense
    Dim l As Integer = 20 'ChartRect.Left
    Dim r As Integer = 700 'ChartRect.Right

    Dim APT() As PointF
    For i = 0 To aData.Length - 1
        Dim iStart As Integer
        Dim iEnd As Integer

        Dim ScaleX As Double
        Dim OrigX As Single

        'Set sampletime to 1 second to keep the predefined scale from above, but still do the calculation as it would be needed with real data:
        ST = 1 ' Rnd()
        Data = aData(i)

        If Data.Length = 0 Then Continue For

        ScaleX = ST * PS_X
        OrigX = Origin.X

        iStart = (l - OrigX) / ScaleX
        iEnd = (r - OrigX) / ScaleX
        If iStart < 0 Then iStart = 0
        If iEnd < 0 Then iEnd = 0
        If iEnd > Data.Length - 1 Then iEnd = Data.Length - 1
        If iStart > Data.Length - 1 Then iStart = Data.Length - 1

        iStart = 0
        iEnd = Data.Length - 1

        If iEnd < iStart Then Continue For

        If ScaleX < 0.3 Then 'more than 3 lines per point, summarize
            Dim iPT As Integer

            Dim FirstX As Integer
            Dim LastX As Integer

            Dim MinY As Single
            Dim MaxY As Single
            Dim tVal As Single

            Dim iSt As Integer
            Dim iEn As Integer


            FirstX = Math.Truncate(iStart * ScaleX)
            LastX = Math.Ceiling(iEnd * ScaleX)

            ReDim APT((LastX - FirstX) * 2 - 1)
            For iX = FirstX To LastX - 1
                MinY = Single.MaxValue
                MaxY = Single.MinValue

                iSt = Math.Truncate(iX / ScaleX)
                iEn = Math.Truncate((iX + 1) / ScaleX) - 1
                If iSt < 0 Then iSt = 0
                If iEn > Data.Length - 1 Then iEn = Data.Length - 1

                For iDat = iSt To iEn
                    tVal = -Data(iDat) * PS_Y
                    If tVal > MaxY Then MaxY = tVal
                    If tVal < MinY Then MinY = tVal
                Next

                iPT = (iX - FirstX) * 2
                APT(iPT) = Origin + New SizeF(iX, MinY)
                APT(iPT + 1) = Origin + New SizeF(iX, MaxY)
            Next


        Else
            ReDim APT(iEnd - iStart)
            For j = iStart To iEnd
                APT(j - iStart) = Origin + New SizeF(j * ScaleX, -(Data(j) * PS_Y))
            Next

        End If




        ImgGR.DrawLines(WFPen, APT)
    Next


    Return Img
End Function
```

Thank you all for taking your time to read my question

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to speed it up by check the distance between points, and skip the ones that are too close to the previous point.

You can skip the sqrt in the distance calculations, and do other optimizations if needed.

To see if this would be beneficial, try running the benchmark using n/2 points.

Comment: i am working on something similar, i am summarizing all points within 1 x-Pixel to 1 line, now one trace does not take loner once it is about 3 times longer [points] than the x-axis size [pixel].

that does not help with a large count of waveforms but seems to be cloes enough to what i need in the real app.

I'll post the optimisations when i reach the optimum.